# Hadoop: Create empty bag if field is null in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have an example of the following data

```
id : long,
list: {(itemId: Long, itemName: charArray)}
```

In my data, list can either be a bag of tuples or null. I would like to change the null into an empty bag (consisting of 0 elements)

I tried something like :

```
answer = FOREACH data
 GENERATE (list is null ? {} : list) AS list;
```

It says that {} and list are not compatible schemas. I am wondering how I can create an empty bag with a compatible schema

I ended up doing this and it worked:

```
answer = FOREACH data
GENERATE (list is null ? (bag{tuple(long,chararray)}){} : list) AS list:{(itemId: long, itemName: charArray)};
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working in Pig 0.11.0...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{}` has no types as is. Bags always have a tuple type inside of it. `list` and your empty bag need to have the same type.

I unfortunately don't have Pig up in a way that I can test this for you and I'm not sure exactly how to do it, but it's going to be something along the lines of this... I couldn't find good documentation on how to set the type of a bag...

Try this perhaps?

```
answer = FOREACH data
GENERATE (list is null ? (bag{tuple(long,chararray)}){} : list) AS list;
```

Comment: thanks much . Was trying == operator but it was not working . this is perfect way for null check ..

Answer (score 3):

If you have the chance to use it, take a look at Apache DataFu project: http://datafu.incubator.apache.org

It has lots of useful stuff for Pig, including `datafu.pig.bags.NullToEmptyBag()`, which does exactly what you are looking for:

```
DEFINE NullToEmptyBag datafu.pig.bags.NullToEmptyBag();
...
answer = FOREACH data GENERATE NullToEmptyBag(list) AS list...;
```

Comment: The other nice thing about NullToEmptyBag is that it preserves the input schema, so you don't have to do something like: (bag{tuple(long,chararray)}){}

Answer (score 0):

empty tuple should be ()

empty bag should be {}

empty map should be []

Comment: Try adding more of an explanation to your answer.